# Can Excel's Find formula have multiple find_text criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, vba

I have a list of names on a NAMES tab range A1:A100.

On another tab 'Data Export', in column A I have an export of thousands of comments where one of those names from the NAME tab can be found within them.  In column B (on my Data Export tab) I am trying to write a formula, FIND or SEARCH ect that will incorporate the range of names in its find_text section.

Find({A1:A100},A2,1)

There must be a way in excel or VBA if someone is hot on that subject, as I am just a beginner, that can accomplish this.  Ideally, in an ideal world, the formula or vba code would return the name that is within a comment in Column B but I understand that that will almost definitely be in VBA territory.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, are you trying to find multiple values in an array or an array of values in a single cell? What about Vlookup?

Comment: @Raystafarian. Vlookup doesn't suit the need. Check Gary'sStudent answer and you would get what's needed.

Comment: Jesus H! Thank you Gary's Student that VB code works better than I expected, returning multiple names if they appear.  It was exactly what I was looking for.  Ace.  Just to finish it off with something I didn't mention previously, how do you make the code not case sensitive?  The code at the comment will not return "hannah" as the name on the 'Names' tab appears as "Hannah"

Comment: In addition, just noticed how some names in a comment will be in complete capitals e.g. "STEVEN".  Is there a way to add an equivalent of the excel's Proper formula around these names so that they match the names on the NAMES tab?

Comment: Please ignore my last message regarding case sensitivity.  My colleagues are so impressed with the outcome of the code 'Gary's Student' created they (and I) were wondering how advanced can this code become to revolutionise a quite frankly flimsy process.  I have prepared a spread sheet to explain what I am going to ask.  Is there a way to up load it to this web-page for you all to see?

Comment: For the close voters: This is not a duplicate. The other question is asking how to find AND REPLACE text in place. This is asking for a summary of matches, leaving the original text in tact. There's a big difference!

Answer (score 1):

If the NAMES tab is like:

```
John
Michael
James
Larry
Moe
Curley
Mike
```

and cell **A1** in the data tab is like:

```
I will invite Mike and John
```

Then in **B1** of the data tab enter:

```
=namelister(NAMES!A1:A100,'Data Export'!A1)
```

In a standard module enter the following **UDF** :

```
Public Function NameLister(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As String
    Dim Sentence As String
    NameLister = ""
    Sentence = r2.Text
    For Each r In r1
        v = r.Text
        If v <> "" Then
            If InStr(1, Sentence, v) > 0 Then
                If NameLister = "" Then
                    NameLister = v
                Else
                    NameLister = NameLister & ", " & v
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

**B1** will display:

```
John, Mike
```

Comment: That should work perfect for your case.